# 4-position TVS/diode array connection

Tags: diodes, schematics, tvs

I'm using a SiLabs USB->UART converter.  In the [documentation](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/cp2102n-datasheet.pdf), it recommends a [specific TVS diode](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/SP0503BAHTG/F2715CT-ND/1154322).  The diode in question has four positions/pins, and appears to be a diode array.  I have never used a diode array before, and am not entirely sure that I understand the wiring of this.

*The diagram for the converter is:*
[image]

*The pinout for the diode is:*
[image]

Is it correct then that I need a single TVS array, with pin 1 to `GND` and pins 2-4 to `VBUS`, `D+`, and `D-`?  I'm presuming that's correct, but figured I'd ask for advice from folk who may have actually used a diode array before.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Andyaka - excellent, thank you!